# C++: Fast Access to Shared Data (Similar to Java Static Members) - Best Practices?

Tags: c++

I made a chess game in Java and translated it to C++, as I want to try to learn it a bit. My problem is that the C++ version is somehow significantly slower (about 2x times). To compile my code, I am using the visual studio compiler, I am also using Qt for the GUI. I built with compiler flag /Ox for optimizations with debug info enabled.

To be more specific about what I mean by slower, I have a function that counts the number of positions with a certain depth. I profiled this function and this is the flame graph:
[image: flame graph]

Everything colored in red is this function:

```
std::vector<int> PGD::getPieceDirections(int piece) {
    int pieceType = (Piece::type(piece) == Piece::PAWN) ?
        Piece::ignoreIndex(piece) : Piece::type(piece);
    return instance->pieceDirections[pieceType];
}
```

All it does it return a vector that has already been precomputed (the type and ignoreIndex functions are just bit operations), but for some reason it's taking a very long time to execute. I am using a singleton class to store and access this data, so that I don't need an actual instance of the class to access the data. I am trying to achieve a similar effect to something like this in java:

```
public class PGD {
    private static HashMap<Integer, int[]> pieceDirections;

    public int[] getPieceDirection(int pieceDirection) {
        return pieceDirections.get(pieceDirection);
    }
}
```

So my questions would be:

1. What is the best practice in order to achieve the same result as in Java?
2. Why exactly is the C++ function so slow to execute? From what I can tell it's creating a new vector maybe, but I don't know why.

**EDIT**
I have also tried

```
const static std::vector<int>& getPieceDirections(int piece);
```

In this case it the flame graph looks basically the same, but the call to getPieceDirections is replaced by a suspicious vector allocation.
[image]

When I profiled this in debug mode, I saw that it was the call to getPieceDirections that slowed me down again.

Comment: Your C++ code doesn't return a precomputed vector - it returns a copy of that vector, which requires memory allocation. Try `const std::vector<int>& PGD::getPieceDirections(int piece) {...}`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I have tried that and edited the post with the results. TLDR, it is still slow

Comment: Show the code that calls `getPieceDirections`. My guess is, *that* code now copies the vector.

Comment: const std::vector<int> directions = PGD::getPieceDirections(tile[index]);
Is this supposed to be & too?

Comment: Make it `const std::vector<int>& directions = PGD::getPieceDirections(tile[index]);` Note the ampersand.

Comment: Yep, that fixed the speed. Thank you very much! I am wondering though about my first question? What is the best way to achieve a similar functionality as my java code? That being a class that holds some data that I can access without having an instance of the class?

Comment: Make all data members and member functions `static`.

Comment: The "best way to achieve a similar functionality" is to actually write C++, instead of Java code using C++ syntax. C++ is not Java, and it works in fundamentally different ways.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google is not a replacement for a C++ textbook. There is no "best way to do <X> in C++" that's universally true. The correct C++ approach for a given task depends on the ***entire*** task, and ***all*** of its specifics. It depends on more than just the half a dozen lines of the shown code. For example, instead of returning a vector from some function, one needs to undestand ***why*** a vector needs to be returned. What is that supposed to accomplish? Is there a better way to do whatever it is, in C++, that does not involve returning a vector, etc???